# Unable to compile uvcvideo driver

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, make

I've been following the LFD103 course titled *"A BEGINNER'S GUIDE TO LINUX KERNEL DEVELOPMENT"*. In the section *"Writing Your First Kernel Patch"*, we make changes to the 'uvcvideo' driver and recompile it. But I just can't get it to work. I added the pr_info() function just as the tutorial mentioned.

```
static int uvc_probe(struct usb_interface *intf,
                 const struct usb_device_id *id)
{
    struct usb_device *udev = interface_to_usbdev(intf);
    struct uvc_device *dev;
    const struct uvc_device_info *info =
            (const struct uvc_device_info *)id->driver_info;
    int function;
    int ret;

    pr_info("I changed uvcvideo driver in the Linux Kernel\n");

    if (id->idVendor && id->idProduct)
            uvc_trace(UVC_TRACE_PROBE, "Probing known UVC device %s "
                            "(%04x:%04x)\n", udev->devpath, id->idVendor,
                            id->idProduct);
    else
            uvc_trace(UVC_TRACE_PROBE, "Probing generic UVC device %s\n",
                            udev->devpath);​
```

After which we configure `CONFIG_USB_VIDEO_CLASS=y`.
`make -j3 all` returns this:
[image]

Kernel version: 6.2.7

What am I doing wrong?
I attempted to resolve the issue by researching on the internet and consulting other sources, but unfortunately, my efforts were unsuccessful. I also tried using `uvc_probe` and `UVC_DBG_PROBE` but it resulted in more errors.
It would be great if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re working off the current mainline kernel, the LFD103 course is slightly outdated, or rather, not as clear as it could be. You must *only* add the `pr_info` line, ignoring the lines around that; so with the kernel as it is today, the result ends up being

```c
static int uvc_probe(struct usb_interface *intf,
             const struct usb_device_id *id)
{
    struct usb_device *udev = interface_to_usbdev(intf);
    struct uvc_device *dev;
    const struct uvc_device_info *info =
        (const struct uvc_device_info *)id->driver_info;
    int function;
    int ret;

    pr_info("I changed uvcvideo driver in the Linux Kernel\n");

    /* Allocate memory for the device and initialize it. */
    dev = kzalloc(sizeof(*dev), GFP_KERNEL);
    if (dev == NULL)
        return -ENOMEM;
```

The `uvc_trace` lines have been modified and are further down the function; they now use `uvc_dbg`:

```c
    if (id->idVendor && id->idProduct)
        uvc_dbg(dev, PROBE, "Probing known UVC device %s (%04x:%04x)\n",
            udev->devpath, id->idVendor, id->idProduct);
    else
        uvc_dbg(dev, PROBE, "Probing generic UVC device %s\n",
            udev->devpath);
```